# How to zoom image on iphone and keep buttons same size, similar to Facebook App image viewer?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to be able zoom an image but keep some sharing and commenting buttons below it a fixed size, similar to the Facebook app. I'm developing a native app, not a web app. What's the best way to achieve this?

[image: Viewing and zooming an image in iPhone Facebook app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the buttons in their own UIView and only zoom the view with your background content in.

To clarify further you should have two UIViews e.g. `buttonView`, `imageView`. `buttonView` will need to sit on top of `imageView`. Image view should allow zooming, `buttonView` should not.

You will need to be careful that your `buttonView` allows pinch touches (assuming thats how you are zooming) to be passed to the `imageView` otherwise zooming wont happen.

Touches are handled in a responder chain. I think it should work ok if only the `imageView` is registered to receive pinch gestures, otherwise you will have to correctly handle the touches and send to the correct UIView

Comment: Thanks that's great. will get it tested and revert back to confirm your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I more than sure that you use UIScrollView for your needs to show all content - comments etc. In this situation I would recommend to open "zooming image view" in additional view for zooming. It can be like overlay over existing view controller or open a new one.

You can get bad user experience when one view is zooming and another one is scrolling for showing whole content to user.